# How to change the header background color of a nested jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an outer accordion and inside it there is another accordion nested. I want to change the header background color of the nested accordion. I tried with the following code

```
$("#nested_accordion.ui-accordion-header").css("background", "red");
// and also:
$("#nested_accordion.ui-accordion.ui-accordion-header").css("background", "red");
```

But the header background color remains the same which is mentioned in the `jquery-ui.css` file. Can anybody help?

Comment: maybe the selector is wrong, try with space: `$("#nested_accordion .ui-accordion-header").css("background", "red");`

Comment: Thanks @reyaner, it works great. I spent several hours behind it without success and a space solved the problem. But I do not know how to mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Np, now you can, i wasnt sure if that was your problem.. what you are doing is selecting an element, that has all of this at once.

Comment: Why not do this with CSS where styling should belong instead of jQuery? `#nested_accordion .ui-accordion-header { background: red; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for nested stuff has to be with space:

```
$("#nested_accordion .ui-accordion-header").css("background", "red");
```